# ¿Cómo implementar constructor default para clase que hereda de SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: java, android, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente clase que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper`  y necesito hacerle un constructor donde reciba el contexto:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements IDataBaseHelper{

private final Context context;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Pero me da este error:

> there is no default constructor avaliable in
>   'android-database.SQLiteOpenHelper'

Answer (score 0):

Los constructores públicos para la clase que extiende de [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) son:

- [SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#public-constructors)
- [SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#public-constructors)
- [SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, int version, SQLiteDatabase.OpenParams openParams)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#public-constructors)

Puedes implementar cualquiera de los anteriores, comunmente se implementa el  constructor [SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#public-constructors) , ejemplo:

```
  public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements IDataBaseHelper{

    private final Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1

       public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
           this.context = context;
       }

       //* Default constructor.
       public DataBaseHelper(Context context, CursorFactory factory) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
       }

      ...
      ...

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Necesita definir usted mismo un constructor explícito que llame al super de 4 o 5 arg en [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Por ejemplo:

```
public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "database.db", null, 1);
}
```

donde database.db es su nombre de archivo de base de datos y 1 es la versión.

Comment: Es importante [dar crédito al autor original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) y también importante es adecuar la respuesta de acuerdo a lo que pregunta el OP https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1298/es-necesario-u-obligatorio-poner-la-fuente-de-una-respuesta-basada-de-soen-o-cu.